# Buttons not displaying on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, button, mobile, css-grid

I'm creating a calculator for a freeCodeCamp project and I've got everything to function and display correctly on my desktop, but when I load the page on my iPhone everything displays except for the actual buttons. I'm using CSS grid for the button layout, so I'm not sure if there is some CSS I need to add there for mobile compatibility. When I searched I kept seeing to add -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; to the CSS, but that didn't work. As a small little side, I can't figure out why the font for the buttons won't change. Any and all help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

The codepen link: https://codepen.io/rorschach1234/pen/gxbbgg

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="top">Electronic Calculator</h2>
    <div class="display">
      <h2 class="displayScreen">0</h2><p class="under">0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
    </div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
$calc-font: 'Orbitron';

body {
  background: #cdc9c9;
}

.container {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #3250ab;
  border: 1px solid #2b4490;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 6px 10px 10px #3d3a38, -3px -3px 10px #3d3a38 ,inset -10px -10px 10px -10px #000000, inset 7px 5px 10px -10px #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.top { 
  font-family: $calc-font;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.display {
  margin: auto 5%;
  background: #a8cda8;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: $calc-font;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #98bf98;
}

.displayScreen {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.under {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 40px);
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "clearall clearD divide multiply"
    "seven eight nine minus"
    "four five six add"
    "one two three equals"
    "zero zero period equals";    
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $calc-font;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#202123, #414245) ;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #999, inset -5px -10px 10px -10px #000000;
}

button:active {
  font-family: $calc-font;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.clearall, .clearD {
  background: #a00b0b;
  color: white;
}
```

The Javascript that creates the buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btnClasses = ["clearall", "clearD", "divide", "multiply", "seven", "eight", "nine", "minus", "four", "five", "six", "add", "one", "two", "three", "equals", "zero", "period"];

  var buttons = ["AC", "CE", "&divide;", "&times;", 7, 8, 9, "-", 4, 5, 6, "+", 1, 2, 3, "=", 0, "."];

  function createButtons() {
    for (var i = 0; i<btnClasses.length; i++) {
      $(".buttons").append("<button class=\"" + btnClasses[i] + "\">" + buttons[i] + "</button>");
      $("." + btnClasses[i]).css("grid-area", btnClasses[i]);
      $("." + btnClasses[i]).css("font-family", "Orbiton");                          
    };
};


  createButtons();
```

Comment: Since you are using css grid your phone browser might not support it. Try checking the current version of your browser and see if it supports css grid.  you can see all the supported versions [Here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

Comment: I think you're right, I'm using an old version iOS, thank you for the help. Any idea why my font for the buttons won't change, even when using my laptop?

Comment: You are setting it directly on the element in your javascript code here `$("." + btnClasses[i]).css("font-family", "Orbiton");` unless you change that your css properties wont take effect.

Comment: Haha wow, that's embarassing, thanks again man!